# Prevent iOS SIGABRT when calling 'UIColor colorWithPatternImage'

Tags: iphone, ipad, uilabel, sigabrt

I am writing an iPad application that has a label with a gradient image background. This has worked in 4.2 but it is working no longer. Every time I try to run I get a SIGABRT whether I am in 4.2 or 4.3. I will put the offending code below, I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
    LabelSingAvg = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, -300, 200, 800)];
LabelSingAvg.text = @"99.8";
LabelSingAvg.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:90];
UIImage *myGradient = [UIImage imageNamed:@"textGradient.png"];
//Line that causes SIGABRT below:
LabelSingAvg.textColor   = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:myGradient];
LabelSingAvg.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
LabelSingAvg.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
LabelSingAvg.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
LabelSingAvg.layer.shadowOpacity = .5;
LabelSingAvg.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0;
LabelSingAvg.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
LabelSingAvg.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);
//LabelSingAvg.alpha = 0.8;
[self.view addSubview:LabelSingAvg];
```

Comment: Are you sure that `myGradient` is not `nil`?

Comment: Well, I think, that your image is nil... Anyway in some really unprobably way it might get released (I really doubt that), in that case, try to write it in one line ;p `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"textGradient.png"]];`

Comment: Please can you post the debugger stack trace for the crash?

Comment: 2011-03-30 09:53:45.646 SeedSense Companion[64941:207] *** Assertion failure in -[UILabel setTextColor:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1447.6.4/UILabel.m:314
2011-03-30 09:53:45.648 SeedSense Companion[64941:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: color'

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Thanks for your help. The image I was referencing got moved out of my resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I got it. Thanks for your help. The image I was referencing got moved out of my resources folder.

Comment: Also, colorWithPatternImage does not retain the image, so you need to keep it around too.